# Simultaneous traverse of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have to read a csv file which has a specific number of fields.I must traverse and detect the consecutive strings of the first column (i have used an array to read the file) and only for these strings, i want to get the sum of their int values in the third column of the file,which i have stored into an another array. So far, i am able to do the detection of the consecutive same strings, but how can i grab their values and get their sum for each string? Is it possible to do this with simultaneous traversal? I don't have experience in java, please help. Thanks.
Here's my code.
The csv file is something like this with random values:

```
ip, timestamp,elapsed,..
127.0.0.1,...,1500
127.0.0.2,...,2800 
127.0.0.2,...,2400
127.0.0.2,...,2500
127.0.0.3,...,1700
127.0.0.4,...,1600
127.0.0.4,...,1500
127.0.0.5,...,2000
```

I must get something like this: 127.0.0.2:7700, 127.0.0.4:3100

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Give file's name: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = in.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputfile = new Scanner(file);

        String csv_data[];
        ArrayList<String> ip_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> elapsed_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] ip_array = new String[ip_list.size()];
        String[] elapsed_array = new String[elapsed_list.size()];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while (inputfile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inputfile.nextLine();
            csv_data = line.split(",");
            ip_list.add(csv_data[0]);
            elapsed_list.add(csv_data[2]);
        }
        ip_array = ip_list.toArray(ip_array);
        elapsed_array = elapsed_list.toArray(elapsed_array);

        for (String element : elapsed_array) {
            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(element);
            } catch (NumberFormatException fe) {
                fe.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(" That's not a number");
            }
        }
        while (i < ip_array.length) {
            int start = i;
            while (i < ip_array.length && (ip_array[i].equals(ip_array[start]))) {
                i++;
            }
            int count = i - start;
            if (count >= 5) {
                System.out.println(ip_array[start] + " " + "|" + " " + count);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what yous problem is specifically. It might help if you edit your question to show an example of the CSV file (just a couple of lines is probably enough) with the output that you expect to get.

Comment: It seems to me that you probably want to use a Map to store pairs of {IP, sum_of_elapsed}. While you traverse the csv file you update records in that map.

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. You dont use "_" in normal variable names, instead you go camelCase!

Comment: And: if you are doing this for a "real" project, consider not re-inventing the wheel. Writing your own CSV parser is way more complicated than you think it is. When your tool will have to deal with arbitrary CSV data, you should rather use some existing library for the parsing part.

Comment: Finally: note that it is 2019 and you are programming in Java. You structure your code like people did 1995 in C. As in: declare your variable with the smallest scope necessary. Do **not** declare all variables in the beginning of your method ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Data> data = read(getFile());
    Map<String, Integer> idSum = groupByIdWithSum(data);
    // ...
}

private static File getFile() throws Exception {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Give file's name: ");
        return new File(in.nextLine());
    }
}

private static List<Data> read(File file) throws Exception {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        List<Data> res = new ArrayList<>();

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            String[] lineParts = scan.nextLine().splie(",");
            res.add(new Data(lineParts[0], Integer.parseInt(lineParts[2])));
        }

        return res;
    }   
}

private static Map<String, Integer> groupByIdWithSum(List<Data> data) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Data d : data)
        map.put(d.getId(), map.getOrDefault(d.getId(), 0) + d.getElapsed());

    return map;
}

final static class Data {
    private final String ip;
    private final int elapsed;

    public Data(String ip, int elapsed) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.elapsed = elapsed;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getElapsed() {
        return elapsed;
    }
}
```